# When I run macro to plot a scatter plot I take parameter not valid

Tags: excel, vba, scatter-plot

this is my code. I want plot a scatter and when run my macro I take `parameter not valid` but when run macro again I don't any error and my line plotted

```
Sub Macro3()
    Dim upx As Variant
    Dim upy As Variant
    upx = "=posh!" & ThisWorkbook.Names(Range("E7").Value).RefersToRange.Address
    upy = "=posh!" & ThisWorkbook.Names(Range("E6").Value).RefersToRange.Address
    With Worksheets("CHARTN").ChartObjects("Chart 11").Chart
        .PlotArea.Select
        .SeriesCollection.NewSeries

        .SeriesCollection(11).XValues = upx
        .SeriesCollection(11).Values = upy
        .SeriesCollection(11).Select
        .SeriesCollection(11).AxisGroup = 2

        .SeriesCollection(11).Select
        .PlotVisibleOnly = True
        .SeriesCollection(11).Select
        With Selection.Format.Line
            .Visible = msoTrue
            .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0)
        End With
        With Selection.Format.Line
            .Visible = msoTrue
            .Weight = 1
        End With
    End With
    
End Sub
```

I try a lot of way but they don't solve my problem
I don't know why I take error in first run

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Try: `Set upx = ThisWorkbook.Names(Range("E7").Value).RefersToRange` and 
  `Set upy = ThisWorkbook.Names(Range("E6").Value).RefersToRange`

Comment: it's not work any way @MGonet